# Query para mostrar datos de usuario y mostrar cantidad

Tags: sql-server

Buenas, estoy actualmente haciendo un query pero creo que ya la cantidad de horas de trabajo me tiene bloqueado.

Trato de mostrar el id de un usuario conjunto con su nombre y apellido, y a todo esto mostrat cuantos prospectos (clientes) tiene asignado.

Mi tabla de usuario tiene los campos cedula, nombres, apellidos
Mi tabla prospecto tiene el campo idusuario (que sería la cedula del usuario)

Quiero mostrar es

idusuario, nombreusuario, apellidousuario, cantidad de prospectos asignados.

Hasta ahora lo que tengo como noción es lo siguiente

```
Select idusuario, count(*) from prospecto
where estado = 1
and usuario is not null
group by idusuario
```

Pero ello refiere a una tabla, ahora quiero es mostrar es dos tablas conjuntas y tengo algo así pero he llegado hasta aquí.

```
select p.IDUSUARIO, u.NOMBRES, u.APELLIDOS, (select count(*) from prospecto where idusuario ) as cantidad 
from PROSPECTO p, USUARIO u
where p.estado = 1
group by p.IDUSUARIO, u.nombres, u.APELLIDOS
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un simple `LEFT JOIN` te dará los resultados:

```
SELECT  u.IdUsuario,
        u.Nombres,
        u.Apellidos,
        ISNULL(p.Cantidad,0) Cantidad
FROM dbo.USUARIO u
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT IdUsuario, COUNT(*) Cantidad
            FROM dbo.PROSPECTO
            WHERE estado = 1
            AND usuario IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY IdUsuario) p
    ON u.IdUsuario = p.IdUsuario;
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias. Justo lo que necesitaba.